# Java Thread Hang

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm creating a Java Slideshow using some 2DTransitions I found on the net. Everything work smoothly, but I come across a problem why trying to execute code after the Slideshow has been rendered. I thought Java threads are used to isolate processes, for instance I have a similar setup with an infinite while loop, and a thread solved that problem. Here it isn't working and I cant figure out why. In the code below I get to the first outputs, but it hangs on thread.run and never prints the last output.

Any ideas why?

Here is the relevant code:

```
System.out.println("Slideshow init");
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  //TODO SLIDESHOW PROBLEM RIGHT HERE
            public void run(){
                int i=0;
                while(keepgoing){
                    if(i==images.size()-1){
                        transit(images.get(images.size()-1),images.get(0));
                        i=0;
                    }
                    else
                        transit(images.get(i),images.get(i+1));
                    i++;
                }       
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Thread created");
        thread.run();
        System.out.println("Thread started");`
```

Comment: I formatted your code properly. You are missing the declaration initialization of "keep going" so I can't tell when this loop will ever end.

Comment: You undid my formatting changes and for some reason I can't roll back the history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not asynchronous.  You need to invoke `start()` not `run()`  Run will execute the Runnable's run method in the current thread.  start will create a new thread which will invoke the run method.

Answer (score 2):

To start a thread, call thread.start().  Calling thread.run() directly doesn't spawn a new thread.